# Despite class/runtimetpye match, assignment fails

Tags: c#, inheritance

EF inherits from E
SF inherits from S
S has attribute subE of type E
Runtime obj of type EF calls AddS(S arg) from its  ancestor class (E) - passing runtime obj of type (SF)
Assignment attempt is in AddS: arg.subE = this
From attached image you can see that the runtime types match, but the assignment fails.

Key for image: E - Event; EF - EventFrameChange;  S - Subscriber; SF - SubscriberFrameChange; AddS() - AddSubscriber; subE - subscribedEvent

[image]

Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

This code works in Unity. Create an empty GameObject in a scene and add a SpriteAnimatorScript as a component.

```
using UnityEngine;

public abstract class Event : ScriptableObject
{
    public Subscriber[] subscribers;

    public void AddSubscriber(Subscriber aSub)
    //
    {
        aSub.subscribedEvent = this;
    }
}

using UnityEngine;

public class EventFrameChange : Event
{
    private SpriteAnimatorScript animatorScript;

    public void Initialize()
    // ^ 
    {
        subscribers = new Subscriber[0];
    }

}

using UnityEngine;

public abstract class Subscriber : ScriptableObject
{
    public Event subscribedEvent;
    // ^ Event this is a subscription to.

    public virtual void SetEvent(Event aEvent)
    {
        subscribedEvent = aEvent;
    }

}

using UnityEngine;

public class SubscriberFrameChange : Subscriber
{
    public new EventFrameChange subscribedEvent;
}

using UnityEngine;

public class SpriteAnimatorScript : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public EventFrameChange eventFrameChange;

    public SubscriberFrameChange subscriberFrameChange;

    void Start () 
    {
        SetupEvents();
    }

    private void SetupEvents()
    {
        eventFrameChange = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<EventFrameChange>();
        subscriberFrameChange = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<SubscriberFrameChange>();
        eventFrameChange.AddSubscriber(subscriberFrameChange);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] demonstrating the problem. See [ask] and [tour].

Comment: I am not a frequent StackExchange user - I hope my code delivery and instructions are clear and appropriate.

Comment: Looks like I am basically talking to myself here. Some added info: explicitly casting in Event.AddSubscriber like so: aSub.subscribedEvent = (EventFrameChange)this - causes the assignment to succeed. Though it also breaks the inheritance structure.

Comment: If I throw the code into just a normal C# Console App (tweaking for the lack of Unity), I see `aSub` has two properties named `subscribedEvent`, because your `new` field just shadows the old one (see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326223/overriding-fields-or-properties-in-subclasses)). Although it presents somewhat differently in that environment, might be related. If, in that image, you had expanded `aSub`'s `base`, would it have shown another field with a non-null value?

Comment: @PhilM Yes! There is a non-null version when expanding base. Hrm - I suppose I could get rid of the `new` attribute and then do an explicit casting when using the field in a descendant -  does that sound reasonable?

Comment: @PhilM if you want to post that as an answer I will select it and ty.

Comment: It might make this a duplicate of the answer I linked, but maybe you just need to make the base class Event a property, although the fact you want different types does vary from what that question was asking.

Answer (score 0):

If I throw the code into just a normal C# Console App (tweaking for the lack of Unity), I see `aSub` has two properties named `subscribedEvent`, because your `new` field just shadows the old one. So the assignment from within the base class method is assigning to the base class copy of the field.