# Dictionary inherited from base class cannot be added to from derived class

Tags: c#, .net

I have an abstract class for POs.

```
public abstract class PO 
{
  public abstract Dictionary<string, object> InvalidFields { get; }
  public abstract string PONumber { get; set; }
}
```

Which is inherited by two different types of PO: CPO and POR.

```
public class CPO 
{
  private string poNumber;

  public override Dictionary<string, object> InvalidFields => new Dictionary<string, object>();
  public override string PONumber
  {
    get 
    {
      return poNumber;
    }
    set 
    {
      if (!ValidatePONumber(value)) InvalidFields.Add("CPO Number", value);
      poNumber = value;
    }
  }
}
```

When `ValidatePONumber(value)` returns `false`, it correctly executes `InvalidFields.Add()` but the dictionary is never actually added to. In the Locals window, a new variable is created named `Namespace.PO.InvalidFields.get returned` and I can see the new key that is added. However, `this.InvalidFields` has no values.

So it looks like the dict in the abstract base class `PO` is being created and added to instead of the derived class `CPO`.

Comment: You are creating a new `Dictionary<string, object>` on every access to `InvalidFields`

Comment: Ok - so the `=>` notation effectively just acts as a `get`?

Comment: Yes, `prop => value;` is the same as `prop { get { return value; } }`

Answer (score 0):

The code as you have given above does not even compile. You derived class is not actually inheriting from the abstract class (I am assuming it is a typo). Even after addition abstract class, the dictionary instantiation throws an error because it is a property definition and missing 'set' definition (InvalidFields is missing 'set' accessor definition.

Also, this sounds to be a duplicate of [Overriding fields or properties in subclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326223/overriding-fields-or-properties-in-subclasses)

I have tried this with minor modifications, please see the code below. Like @yransis says in comments, The InvalidFields is being treated as a 'get' property, returning new instance of dictionary every time it is executing the 'Add' step.

```
class DerivedCpo : AbstractPo
{
    private string poNumber;
    private Dictionary<string, object> invalidFieldsBackingField;
    public override Dictionary<string, object> InvalidFields
    {
        get
        {
            return invalidFieldsBackingField;
        }
        set { this.invalidFieldsBackingField = value; }
    }

    public DerivedCpo()
    {
        this.InvalidFields = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }
    public override string PoNumber
    {
        get { return poNumber;}
        set
        {
            if(!ValidatePONumber((value)))
                InvalidFields.Add("CPO Number", value);
            poNumber = value;
        }
    }



    private bool ValidatePONumber(string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (value.Length > 5)
            return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

Main method calling this class -

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var po = new DerivedCpo();
    po.PoNumber = "test1";
    po.PoNumber = "thisistheinvalidfieldpo";

    if (po.InvalidFields != null && po.InvalidFields.Count > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(@"There are {0} fields in invalidFields collection", Convert.ToString(po.InvalidFields.Count) );
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

In the code above I have added explicit backing field. It is being instantiated only once in the constructor. That way the contents of InvalidFields are persistent. In your code, you are returning a new instance of dictionary, essentially losing the data that was stored between two 'get' calls.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Klaus for pointing out the issue. I resolved by setting up a private `invalidFields` field and returning that with `InvalidFields.get` because what I was doing was returning a new Dictionary class with every `get`.

```
public class CPO : PO
{
  private string poNumber;
  private Dictionary<string, object> invalidFields = new Dictionary<string, object>();

  public override Dictionary<string, object> InvalidFields { get => invalidFields; }
  public override PONumber
  {
    get 
    {
      return poNumber;
    }
    set 
    {
      if (!ValidatePONumber(value)) InvalidFields.Add("CPO Number", value);
      poNumber = value;
    }
  }
}
```