# In C#, why doesn't a subclass field's default value override the superclass field's default value?

Tags: c#

I'm sure this is a duplicate but I can't find an answer. I'm new to C# and having trouble understanding why this is happening:

I have one class that inherits from another. I want the subclass to override a public field on the superclass, in this case the public field `a`. But it doesn't seem to work:

```
class Foo
{
   public string a = "x";

   public string A()
   {
      return a;
   }
}

class Bar : Foo
{
   public string a = "y";
}

...

new Foo().A() // Returns "x"
new Bar().A() // Returns "x" also...why?
```

I would expect the last line to return `"y"` but instead it returns `"x"`, ignoring the fact that I've overridden the value of the `a` field. Why isn't it working? And what is the standard way of getting the behavior I want?

I'm entering this code into the `csharp` REPL, if that matters.

Comment: Methods are overridden, not fields. You can use virtual methods for this behavior.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326223/overriding-fields-or-properties-in-subclasses

Comment: Note the compiler warning about this: `'Bar.a' hides inherited member 'Foo.a'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended`. This hints that something is not good with this code and in fact, you aren't overriding the field as you think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is shadowing the field, not overriding it.

It's the equivalent of this code:

```
class Bar : Foo
{
    public new string a = "y";
}
```

Your compiler should have given you a warning on this code.

Now, since you're shadowing it means that in a call to `A` the field in `Foo` is used and it's like the field in `Bar` doesn't exist.

You can't override a field, but if you change the field to a property then you can do this:

```
class Foo
{
    public virtual string a { get; set; } = "x";

    public string A()
    {
        return a;
    }
}

class Bar : Foo
{
    public override string a { get; set; } = "y";
}
```

Now your code would behave as you first thought it would:

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(new Foo().A()); //x
    Console.WriteLine(new Bar().A()); //y
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to mark property `a` with `virtual` and override it in the subclass.

In Foo: `public virtual string a { get; set; } = "x";`

In Bar: `public override string a { get; set; } = "y";`

Comment: Technically there is also the [`new` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier), which might be more in line with what the OP was expecting.